# Login to Facebook Connect using JavaScript SDK freezes in Opera?

Tags: authentication, facebook, opera

I have a Facebook Connect site under development. The login works great on Firefox, IE, Safari and Chrome. But when I test it using Opera (using the latest version = 11) I run into problems.

I get to the point where I get the login form pop-up, fill it in with my email and password and click the login button. After that the login window becomes empty and the window title says "XD Proxy".

I am using the Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK and there are some iFrames (displayed in the jQuery lightbox-style plugin "ColorBox") in my solution.

Do you know if there are problems with Opera and Facebook Connect, or if there's something in my code that causes this? As I said, the solution has been tested in all the other major browsers and work fine there.

Thanks in advance!

/Thomas

PS. On the development server I'm running the site on port number 8585. I've seen some posts on the net saying this can cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution that seems to work! If I add a channelUrl option to FB.init, I can log in. I got a warning from Opera saying the following:

> Warning
>   http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html?fb_xd_fragment
>
> A page on the public Internet requests
>   data from your private intranet. For
>   security reasons, automatic access is
>   blocked, but you may choose to
>   continue.
>
> LINK: Continue
>
> LINK: Always continue when data is
>   requested from this server on my
>   private intranet

I clicked the link "Continue" and after that it worked (during this session). The original FB.init line looked like this (appId and some other stuff has been replaced in this example):

```
// Facebook init
FB.init({ appId: '123456789', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true });
```

After I had added the channelUrl it looked like this:

```
// Facebook init
FB.init({ appId: '123456789', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, channelUrl: "http://www.yourdomain.com/channel.html" });
```

The file "channel.html" is a simple file that contains just this line of code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_EN/all.js"></script>
```

Create it and put it on your server at the location you have specified in the channelUrl. The server root is a good place.

The next step is figuring out how to get rid of the Opera warning, if it's possible at all?

Good luck!

/Thomas Kahn

Comment: I've tried what this but the page freezes but without any url in the toolbar of browser where we write the website and go! (sorry, i don't know the exacly word in English). Without the channelUrl it freezes but remains a link in the toolbar (pointing to facebook plataform)

Answer (score 5):

Facebook connect currently fails because Facebook's scripts "detect" Internet Explorer by checking if the attachEvent method is supported. Unfortunately, Opera supports this method (historically for compatibility with other sites that needed it). Now, if they only did this: https://github.com/facebook/connect-js/pull/240 ..

This broken pseudo-browser-detection causes the problem because Facebook happens to use some IE code that Opera does not support to embed Flash for cross-document messaging in the Flash-based part of the script, while the alternate window.postMessage() part of the script has other problems as described here: http://my.opera.com/hallvors/blog/2010/07/20/postmessage-s-targetorigin-and-security

Comment: Thank you for explaining the background! In fact, I had discovered and read your blogpost before I asked the question here, but to be honest I didn't understand everything and wasn't sure if it was the same problem as the one I was experiencing. As I mentioned above, I have some sort of solution working for Opera now but the warning I get is not desireable.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it in Opera, just add the following after FB.init():

```
if($.browser.opera ) // it uses jQuery library here!
{
   FB.XD._transport="postmessage";
   FB.XD.PostMessage.init();
}
```

Comment: I get an error message saying: "Invalid Argument. Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration." Do I have to change any configuration settings? Should I keep the channelUrl parameter in the FB.init arguments?

Comment: @tkahn This is set up in your Facebook Application settings. The url specified there must be the url you run your website on.

Answer (score 1):

This channel.html dont work for me

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_EN/all.js"></script>
```

but when I change it to:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js"></script>
```

it works. In this url is not valid content http://connect.facebook.net/en_EN/all.js there is something wr go to this instead http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js

Comment: There is no such a thing as en_EN. You have to choose between en_US (American English) or en_GB (Brittish English). You'll find the complete list of locales here: http://www.facebook.com/translations/FacebookLocales.xml